# act on all children at once on pyqt widget

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt

is it possible to somehow obtain possibility to control all the children of a certain Qt.Widget?
For example in a Qgroupbox I have many QtextEdits that I want to clear (clear contents, not delete) at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. However, you can easily find the child widgets of your groupbox and iterate over them. I think that is your best option.

Something like this:

```
[textEditor.clear() for textEditor in myGroupBox.findChildren(QtGui.QTextEdit)]
```

You can add a name parameter to [findChildren](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qobject.html#findChildren) if you want to filter further by the objectName property of your QTextEdits.

Comment: The closest approximation would be to connect a signal (e.g. a button-click) to the `clear()` slot of each text-edit. But iterating over the widgets is probably more flexible.

Comment: I would say your solution is even more in-line with the Qt way of working. Signals and slots ... they're made for this.

Comment: Thanks, I always somehow do the lousy copy-code work for all I need instead of using the python's possibilities. Findchildren did the work I need, thanks